# d13slideshow for WordPress and "URL file-access is disabled"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm taking my chances with WordPress 3.0 beta 1 (single user)

Unfortunately, i ran into problems with d13slideshow.
I configured the plugin to display 5 latest from a category, added `<?php d13slideshow(); ?>` to home.php, but it bombed:

`function.getimagesize: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /<snip>/wp-content/plugins/d13slideshow/d13slideshow.php on line 538
Warning:  getimagesize(http://<snip>/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/featured-2-580x386.jpg) function.getimagesize: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /<snip>/wp-content/plugins/d13slideshow/d13slideshow.php on line 538`

Is this a problem with the php setup or is there something I can do with the plugin or the function call from the template files to make it work?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/d13slideshow/

Comment: Did this work before with an earlier version of WP?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. We used Dynamic Content Gallery before, but needed something easier for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a configuration stuff... you will have to edit your php.ini and change the allow_url_include option from Off to On. For example

```
# nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
allow_url_include = On
```

Then, you will have to restart apache:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You will have to use the correct paths for your server ;)

Tell me if that works...

Comment: That's the problem, I want a solution that can be reused across different php configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have access to your php.ini file due to hosting restrictions. Ask you host or check for an update to that plugin.